# Discord.js - How to play a video from a bot?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have successfully played a audio from a youtube link, now i am trying to play both the audio and the video from the bot, is it possible? In discord, you get a option to share your video, so I thought it can be possible.

I searched on discord.js and found no documentation related to starting video and stuffs. So, How can you play both audio and video with discord.js

My code of playing audio :-

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

module.exports = {
    name: 'play_music',
    description: "Plays the music",
    async execute(message, args){
        const memberInGroup = [];
        let musicChannel;

        let fullArg = '';
        args.forEach(part => {
            fullArg = fullArg + part + ' ';
        });
        fullArg = fullArg.trimEnd();

        const validate = ytdl.validateURL(fullArg);
        
        if(!validate) {
            message.channel.send("Plzz enter a valid Youtube Url");
        } else {

        const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(fullArg);
        console.log(songInfo.videoDetails.video_url);

        const channels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.id === 'myChannelId' && c.type === 'voice');
        for (const [channelID, channel] of channels) {
            musicChannel = channel;
            for (const [memberID, member] of channel.members) {
              memberInGroup.push(memberID);
            }
        }

        if(!memberInGroup.includes(message.author.id)) {
            message.channel.send("You must be in the music group.");
        } else {
            message.channel.send("Playing music");
            musicChannel.join().then(connection => {
                const dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(songInfo.videoDetails.video_url))
                    
                dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
                    connection.disconnect();
                })
            })
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot play video using `discord.js` or any other library related to discord nor you can do it in any other way , discord is a chatting and voice streaming platform not a video sharing platform

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an experience with discord js but from what i have seen in the bots that were made the only thing that you can play is audio you can send a link to youtube via your bot and users will play them thats the only solution.